# Numpy, выровнять массив

Tags: python, numpy

Есть двумерный массив, типа:

```
lst = [[100, 101, 103, 104],
       [101, 103, 104, 105],
       [103, 220, 221, 105],
       [104, 221, 221, 106],
       [105, 105, 106, 106]]
```

Сам массив это карта глубины, расстояния до плоски + до объекта по центру, по ней видно что горизонт изображения завален, как я могу выровнять его?
Предполагаю, что мне надо взять 4 угловых точки и высчитать угол наклона, а дальше умножить каждый элемент массива на это число?

upd
Картинка примерно такая, цвета от синего до красного, чем синее тем значение точки меньше, тут видно что лево вверх ниже, чем право низ
Примерно такой массив на выходе только 640х480

```
lst = [[100, 101, 103, 104],
       [101, 103, 104, 105],
       [103, 104, 105, 105],
       [104, 105, 105, 106],
       [105, 105, 106, 106]]
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

но картинка не равномерная, там ещё объекты разные есть
поэтому сначала хочу найти коэфы на фото где нет объектов, а потом уже на всех остальных картинках применить его и выровнять

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Хорошо бы картинку какую приложить. Из описания непонятно, где здесь наклон.

Comment: Так а что в итоге нужно - чтобы граничные числа стали примерно одинаковыми всё пересчитать? Чтобы полоски снизу, сверху, справа и слева стали одинаковыми примерно по величине?

Comment: @CrazyElf да, чтобы весь кадр стал ровнее стал, допустим кадр наклонён на 15 градусов и надо каждую точку повернуть на свой кф

Comment: А банально из первой матрицы вычесть вторую (или из второй картинки первую) - не подойдёт разве? У вас значения довольно грубые, при 3D повороте и "координаты" точек поплывут. Потом аппроксимировать до целых координат? Да и по значениям из примера у вас не плоскость вроде, а нечто гнутое по диагонали.

Comment: @GrAnd так первая тоже наклонена, нет это именно плоскость, стол компьютерный, на нем лежит мышка, при съемке камера была немного наклонена, и нужно выровнять картинку, координаты как раз не думал двигать (x, y), чисто ось Z подвытянуть где надо

Comment: @Leonid Ну так отсканируйте плоскость стола. И потом вычитайте значения этого скана для каждой точки из других сканов, как я уже предложил.

Comment: @GrAnd так а что это мне даст? немного не понимаю, вот у меня есть стол с наклоном, далее у меня есть стол с наклоном и объектами, после удаления у меня останутся только объекты? но ведь они всё равно будут под наклоном. Или отсканировать ровный стол и его вычитать из всех картинок?